# I want to display an approximation of pi making use of only the first five terms from the infinite series that helps compute pi

Tags: python-3.x, pi

pi = 3 + (4/(2x3x4)) - (4/(4x5x6)) + (4/(6x7x8)) - (4/(8x9x10)) + (4/(10x11x12)) - (4/(12x13x14)) + (4/(14x15x16)) + ...

I tried a little something but the output shows something different.

```
a, b, c = 2, 3, 4
x = 4/(a*b*c)

pi = 3
for i in range(5):
    pi += x
    a = c
    b = a + 1
    c = b + 1
    x *= -1

print(pi)
```

Comment: Python doesn't substitute in that formula for X.  You need to say `x = 4/(a*b*c)` every time.  You'll need to track the +1/-1 separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
a, b, c = 2, 3, 4
four = 4

pi = 3
for i in range(5):
    pi += four/(a*b*c)
    a = c
    b = a + 1
    c = b + 1
    four *= -1

print(pi)
```